# Multiplying individual values within a dataframe individually

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a simple weighting tool for age and gender values.  The script first looks at the way gender is distributed, compares that to the desired distribution, and updates the weight column accordingly (e.g., going from 1 to 1.12).  Then it looks at the way age is distributed (keeping in mind the newly assigned weights), compares that to the desired distribution, and updates the weight column again.

It works fine the first go-round, but it doesn't work in the second step.  I know why, but am at a loss of how to fix.  It looks like it's picking up the first values it sees and applying it across the board, whereas I really need it to evaluate each cell individually.

Take this as an example: In the first round, female cells get a .98, and male cells get a 1.02.  Then it goes to calculate the age weights, and it's looking for an age value of 1.  Suppose the first age=1 value it sees is a female.  It then goes and multiplies the age=1 weight by .98 for ALL age=1 cells, even though males with an age value of = 1 should really be multiplied with the 1.02.

Below is a fully-functioning version of my script on a subset of data.  How can I get it to evaluate each cell individually?

```
    weightdict = {'Gender' : {1 : .49, 2 : .51}, 'Age' : {1 : 0.08, 2 : .27, 3 : .31, 4 : .34}}
    weightframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(weightdict,orient='columns')
    df = {'Gender': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2},
    'Age': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 3}}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df,orient='columns')
df.loc[:,'Weight'] = 1 #add a dummy weight column

def getaverage(column):
    average = df.groupby(column)['Weight'].sum()/df['Weight'].sum() #find distribution within dataset for each value
    average = weightframe[column].div(average) #find what % the value is still under/overrepresented
    average = average.reset_index()
    average = average.rename(columns={'index' : 'variable',0 : column})
    return average

def multiply(x):
    value = df.loc[df[column]==x,column].iloc[0] #get value from table to evaluate
    weight = df.loc[df[column]==value,'Weight'].iloc[0] #get the value's currently assigned weight
    newvalue = average.loc[average['variable']==value, column].iloc[0] #get the value's degree of over/underrepresentation
    return newvalue*weight #multiply the new weight by the old weight

for column in list(df)[0:2]:
    average = getaverage(column) #get set of averages for column
    df['Weight'] = df[column].apply((lambda x : multiply(x)))
    print(df)
```

Comment: The function multiply is using global variables `df` and `column` inside of an `apply()` which is an *exceptional* bad idea.  Suggest you fix that and then see if your problems magically vanish.  If they don't, then I suggest you update this post with better code and the expected results in the form of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'd love to post "better" code, but I'm quite new to Python and don't follow why it's bad practice (or what I could be doing differently, hence why I posted).  It'd be helpful if you elaborated?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of global vs local variables?

Comment: Conceptually, yes.  But I'm not sure how to apply them in this instance.

Comment: Instead of `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, ...` you can do `[1, 2, 2, ...`.  The 0-N index is implied.

Comment: In this case in multiply(), you are using a variable that are defined outside of the function (ie: global).  If you are referencing globals, you can get side effects, many of which can cause the problems you are seeing.  This is why you should avoid using them.  One problem that is likely causing you problems could be improved by doing `df[column].apply(lambda x : multiply(x), axis=1)`.  Anyways, Good Luck....

Comment: So, should I copy the variables and make local ones within the function?  What I struggle with is trying to rewrite it so that they are not global.  Your suggestion unfortunately didn't work, as pandas considers df[column] a series, and therefore cannot accept axis as part of lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand exactly what your final output should contain, but I think I understand enough to provide some help.

Starting with your df and weights, I get a table that looks like this (I left off the dummy weight column for now):

```
weightdict = {
               'Gender': {1: 0.49, 2: 0.51}, 
                  'Age': {1: 0.08, 2: 0.27, 3 : .31, 4 : .34}
              }
weightframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(weightdict,orient='columns')

df = {
      'Gender': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2},
         'Age': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 3}
     }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df,orient='columns')

df

Out[]: 
   Age  Gender
0    3       1
1    3       2
2    2       2
3    1       1
4    4       2
5    2       1
6    3       2
7    4       1
8    4       1
9    3       2
```

You can then loop through the `Age` and `Gender` columns and create a new column that represents their respective weights:

```
for col in df[0:2]: 
    # create a dict (printed for clarity) with the calculated weight 
    # for each entry to feed to the following `map` statements
    dist = {idx: count/len(df) for idx, count in df[col].value_counts().items()}
    print(col)
    print(dist)
    df[col + 'Weight'] = df[col].map(weightdict[col]) / df[col].map(dist)

df

-----
Age
{3: 0.40000000000000002, 4: 0.29999999999999999, 
 2: 0.20000000000000001, 1: 0.10000000000000001}
Gender
{2: 0.5, 1: 0.5}
```

The resulting df looks like this:

```
Out[]: 
   Age  Gender  AgeWeight  GenderWeight
0    3       1   0.775000          0.98
1    3       2   0.775000          1.02
2    2       2   1.350000          1.02
3    1       1   0.800000          0.98
4    4       2   1.133333          1.02
5    2       1   1.350000          0.98
6    3       2   0.775000          1.02
7    4       1   1.133333          0.98
8    4       1   1.133333          0.98
9    3       2   0.775000          1.02
```

You can then perform calculations across rows. I'm not sure if this is the actual calculation you wanted, but you should be able to adapt this approach.

```
df['Weighted'] = df.AgeWeight * df.GenderWeight

df

Out[16]: 
   Age  Gender  AgeWeight  GenderWeight  Weighted
0    3       1   0.775000          0.98  0.759500
1    3       2   0.775000          1.02  0.790500
2    2       2   1.350000          1.02  1.377000
3    1       1   0.800000          0.98  0.784000
4    4       2   1.133333          1.02  1.156000
5    2       1   1.350000          0.98  1.323000
6    3       2   0.775000          1.02  0.790500
7    4       1   1.133333          0.98  1.110667
8    4       1   1.133333          0.98  1.110667
9    3       2   0.775000          1.02  0.790500
```

Clean up df:

```
del df['AgeWeight']
del df['GenderWeight']

df

Out[12]: 
   Age  Gender  Weighted
0    3       1  2.278500
1    3       2  2.371500
2    2       2  2.754000
3    1       1  0.784000
4    4       2  4.624000
5    2       1  2.646000
6    3       2  2.371500
7    4       1  4.442667
8    4       1  4.442667
9    3       2  2.371500
```